# Access internet over Wifi instead of ethernet

Tags: networking, 16.04, network-manager, internet, iptables

I am setting up networking on my `ODROID C1` running `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.10.104-181 armv7l)`
. Internet access over WiFi works fine but when I plug-in the ethernet cable (which has no internet) the internet stops working. I tried solution provided here - [How to set up dual wired and wireless connections?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/10741/how-to-set-up-dual-wired-and-wireless-connections) and `route add default dev wlxe84e060e7296 metric 20` as provided here - [Make wifi preferable over wired connection in Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452746/make-wifi-preferable-over-wired-connection-in-ubuntu-14-04) without any success.

**Relevant Network Manager screens:**

[image: Network connections]

[image: Use this connection only for the resources on its network]

**Here is the output from `ifconfig`:**

```
odroid@odroid:~$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for odroid:
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:06:10:3e:53
          inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::21e:6ff:fe10:3e53/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22741 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53798 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:3353321 (3.3 MB)  TX bytes:69942053 (69.9 MB)
          Interrupt:40

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:80055 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:80055 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:297303646 (297.3 MB)  TX bytes:297303646 (297.3 MB)

wlxe84e060e7296 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr e8:4e:06:0e:72:96
          inet addr:192.168.225.208  Bcast:192.168.225.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ea4e:6ff:fe0e:7296/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1345 errors:0 dropped:2 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4769 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:121706 (121.7 KB)  TX bytes:551025 (551.0 KB)

odroid@odroid:~$
```

Comment: You might need to set the `metrics` for which interface has priority.  Look here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/708319/how-to-use-network-metric-to-manage-two-nics-in-one-pc

Comment: @Terrance I did tried that `route add default dev wlxe84e060e7296 metric 20` with no success.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Managed to fix this, updated DNS to wifi adapter via Network Manager and it worked

Comment: This explanation would gain significantly from a little more detail.